# Session expiry management for spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

I have set session timeout of 3mins in my project:

My application.yml file

```
  servlet:
     contextPath: /
     session:
        cookie:
          name: TEST_SESSION
          max-age: 180
        timeout: 180
```

web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <name>WMS_JSESSIONID</name>
    </cookie-config>
    <session-timeout>
        3
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

My SecurityConfig.java

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 http
                .requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure().and() 
                .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login**")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new SpLoginUrlAuthenticaitonEntryPoint("/login"))
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .successHandler(spAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(spAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .deleteCookies("SESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .rememberMe().alwaysRemember(false).rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices()).key(internalSecretKey).tokenValiditySeconds(1200000)
                .sessionManagement()
                .invalidSessionUrl("/login?sessionExpired=true")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable().cors();
    }
```

I have added url for invalid session redirect.

Issue: I have set timeout of 3mins, yet after 3mins it does not automatically redirect to /login page. I am able to perform other actions(save/fetch data) even after 3mins. ONLY ON REFRESH it redirects to session expiry url.

I want to session expiry redirects only for logged in users. Currently without login , upon refresh after 3mins it is getting redirected to the sessionexpiry url.

Comment: If it works after a browser refresh it means that your browser is caching. Show your request log from your dev tool (F12).

Comment: If the session is expired you don't know anymore that your user was logged in. All informations are gone.